# Python: How can I get input between 1 and 10?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, input, output

```
while True:
    print ("wanna exit? type a number that not between(1-11)range")
    side1 = input("Type 1st side: ")
    side2 = input("Type 2st side: ")
    side3 = input("Type 3rd side: ")
    a= [1,11]
    if   (side1 not in a) :
            print("You exit,goodbye! ")
            break
    else:
            a = int(side1)
            b = int(side2)
            c= int(side3)
            perimeter = (a + b +c )
            print ("The perimeter of triangle is :", perimeter )
```

i input a number between 1 and 10 , however it outputed "you exit...." again and again

Comment: `[1, 11]` is a two-element list, not a closed interval. (Also, if you're on Python 3, `input` always returns a string.)

Comment: `if side1 not in [1,11]` does not check for values within the _range_ of one to eleven; it only checks those two specific individual values .  You want `if not 1 <= side1 <= 11` instead.

Comment: I think you need a more descriptive title question. Please mention some keywords like "Python", "condition", "loop", etc.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns a string, while `a` stores only integers. Second, you need to create a range of values, not just a list of `[1, 11]`.

```
side1 = int(input("Type 1st side: "))
side2 = int(input("Type 2st side: "))
side3 = int(input("Type 3rd side: "))
a= range(1, 12)
```

Comment: If OP meant to include 11 as part of a closed range they should want `range(1,12)` Also, I believe the `list(...)` is unnecessary

Comment: @ChrisCameron thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.